# Генерация Web.Config transform из сущестующих файлов конфигурации

Tags: .net, asp.net

Есть два файла конфигурации:

- web.config с машины разработчика (с тестовыми путями), лежащий под source control
- web.config с живой машины, бывший когда-то полной копией первого (кроме connection string), но в который уже на живой машине внесено множество правок.

Хочется настроить автодеплой. Для автодеплоя нужен XML Document Transform - Web.release.config.

Структура файлов одинакова, имена настроек - одинаковы. Но их много. Руками переносить и сверять - долго.

Подскажите способ автоматической генерации XDT по двум файлам конфига.

Comment: Если все совсем плохо - можно просто повесить `xdt:Transform="Replace"` на корневой элемент...

Comment: @PavelMayorov нет, хотелось бы именно diff - проект развивается, и не хотелось бы вручную вносить изменения в структуру сразу двух конфигов. но спасибо за вариант!

Comment: А какого рода правки? Можете привести упрощённый пример?

Comment: (Я не большой знаток XML, поэтому наверное написал бы велосипед, который парсит оба файла и считает дифф вручную. Хотя наверное имея ручной дифф, недолго и XDT сваять.)

Comment: @VladD там дифф вида `<add name="MyDB" 
      connectionString="value for the deployed Web.config file" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>`. Т.е. если заменить в таком диффе весь xml всего файла - то придётся любое изменение конфига вручную вносить в дифф. Скорее всего есть готовые велосипеды (я выгуглил https://github.com/CameronWills/FatAntelope, но нет возможности проверить. Надеялся что есть стандартный способ - так что если нет, то не утруждайтесь, я попробую сам набросать :)

Comment: @VladD вот статья о самой фмче трансформаций -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PashaPash: Не то чтобы его нету, просто мне он не попадался (специфика десктопной специализации).

Comment: @PashaPash: Ага, уже открыто в соседнем табе.

Comment: @VladD если антилопа взлетит, и никто не предложит стандартный способ - запощу её как ответ. Но если честно, я не сразу её нашёл.

Comment: Не понял, что и как должно мёрджиться...

Comment: @Qwertiy стандартный способ: есть dev конфиг + дифф настройки для паблиша (xdt, web.release.config) -> release web.config. у меня есть dev web.config и web.config c боевого сервера. надо на их основе получить xdt для цепочки - чтобы не править конфиг на боевом сервере вручную, а запусткать стандартный паблиш. грубо говоря, мне нужен diff двух xml с одинаковой структурой, отличающихся лишь значениями аттрибутов в формате xdt.

Comment: Почему-то мне кажется, что надо все настройки с прода перетащить на dev, кроме двух перечисленных, а не шаманить вокруг мёрджа, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy нет. там абсолютные пути к файлам, урлы внешних живых сервисов, вобщем, неудобно. да еще и дев по структуре новее чем прод - пару старых секций выкосили. я нашел и проверил готовую тулзу - сейчас оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел готовую утилиту, [FatAntelope (github)](https://github.com/CameronWills/FatAntelope), которая делает ровно то, что нужно.

Сгенерировал diff и за пару минут подчистил его до релизного состояния.

Синтаксис вызова:

```
FatAntelope source-file target-file output-file [transformed-file]
   source-file : (input) original config file path.  E.g. the development web.config
   target-file : (input) final config file path.  E.g. the production web.config
   output-file : (output) file path to save the generated patch.  E.g. web.release.config
```

Есть онлайн-версия на https://fatantelopetester.apphb.com/ — если вам не страшно лить свои явки и пароли в интернет :)

Пост автора тулзы на en.SO: [Generating xml document transformation for Staging and Production web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33659202/1988244)